# Java - define private fields using only one private keyword

Tags: java, field, private

Is there a way for me to define private fields using only one `private` keyword?
What I'm really asking is: is there something that I can do that looks like this:

```
private {
    int x;
    int y;
    Object myObject;
    //etcetera
};
```

and `x`, `y`, and `myObject` will all be created as private fields

Comment: you can do private int x,y; //if that helps

Comment: I knew about that, I was just wondering whether you could take that a step further and use other data types as well.

Answer (score 2):

No. Its not possible to define variables of different datatypes in a single block. Closest is this:

```
private int x,y;
private Object myObject;
```

Comment: ok. I guess that makes sense, because they probably don't want people to mix the data types.